# How to create a copy of the initial state of an array?

Tags: angular

I have ratings, that get fetched from a postgres database and displayed in a table.
When I edit a rating, I can only add or remove tags to it through a input like element which comes from my "TagInputComponent".

The TagInputComponent looks like this:

```
import { Component, DoCheck, IterableDiffers, OnInit, Input, Output } from 'angular2/core';
import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Component({
    selector: 'taginput',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/taginput.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['assets/stylesheets/taginput.css']
})
export class TagInputComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
@Input() tags: string[];
newTag = '';
oldTags: string[];
differ: any;

constructor(differs: IterableDiffers) { 
    this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
}

ngOnInit() { }

ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.tags);

    if (changes) {
        changes.forEachAddedItem(r => console.log('added ' + r.item));
        changes.forEachRemovedItem(r => console.log('removed ' + r.item));
    }
}
```

It gets used in the DataFormComponenet like this:

```
<taginput [tags]="datapoint.tags"></taginput>
```

How do I create a copy of `tags` to `oldTags` once it is filled with data?

It noticed that `ngOnInit()` is too early as the data is not yet there from the service. With `ngDoCheck()` it always updates to the currentState.

It seems like a simple task, but I just can't find out how to do it.

---

igorzg answer worked for me, although I changed it to my needs. This is what I did:

```
ngDoCheck() {
    var changes = this.differ.diff(this.tags);

    if (changes) {
        if (Array.isArray(changes.collection) && !this.oldTags) {
            this.oldTags = changes.collection.slice();
        }

        changes.forEachAddedItem(r => console.log('added ' + r.item));
        changes.forEachRemovedItem(r => console.log('removed ' + r.item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
   if (Array.isArray(changes.tags) && !this.oldTags) {
     this.oldTags = changes.tags.slice();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about setter?

```
@Input()
set tags(tags: string[]) {
  this.oldTags = tags.slice();
  _tags = tags;
}
```